# Указать ид, равный нулю

Tags: yii

Пытаюсь для нового элемента указать ид = 0. Но ни через контроллер не проходит, ни через форму. Это вообще не реализуемо, что ли?
Поле ид, естественно, примари кей и автоинкремент.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы указываете `id=0` (будет так же и с `id=NULL`) для поля `AUTO_INCREMENT`, СУБД сама устанавливает `id` последним в таблице.

Можно использовать операцию

```
SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

перед вашим SQL запросом? чтоб СУБД не изменяла `id=0`.

Другой вопрос в том, действительно ли вам нужна запись с `id=0`?

Comment: Так я не знаю, какой счетчик стоит в бд. Может, имеет смысл кидать 
`ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0'`
перед запросом?

Но опять же как это реализовать в yii?  
И почему `id=0` не есть тру? Считается, что первая запись в таблице есть `id = 1`? Просто, я программист, для меня первый ид = 0.

Comment: @anunak в классических таблицах нумерация PRIMARY_KEY представляет собой UNSIGNED INT и начинается с 1. Если стоит AUTO_INCREMENT, программисту не нужно следить за тем с каким `id` он работает (без особой нужды). `id=0` встречал только в какой-то CMS (вроде Drupal, но могу ошибаться). `ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> AUTO_INCREMENT=0` сбросит ваш счетчик и это породит проблемы с вставкой новых записей в конец таблицы, не надо так делать. Если вы можете отказаться от `id=0` в пользу `id=1`, то освободите себя от лишних проблем.